# Nuxt validate method on a whole folder

Tags: vue.js, routes, nuxt.js

I have been able to validate for a single page dynamic route like this:
/:username

I'm not quite sure how to validate the above along with:

```
/:username/friends
/:username/profile
/:username/profile/edit
/:username/any/number/of/nested/routes
```

and so on without repeating and slightly editing the same code across all the pages.

I tried to create a _.vue and have the validate method in there instead of in _username/index.vue and having a 'username.vue' outside of the _username folder to wrap it but that did not work either. Is there a way to have a central validate method that would do the above?